# Router port forwarding and rtsp streaming problem

Tags: java, streaming, portforwarding, vlcj

I'm using vlcj to stream (RTSP) video.
The problem is I am behind a router and dd-wrt only forwards and open ports if there is an application that is listening. But, I stream video, I don't listen on ports that are streaming...

How can I get around this problem?
Everything works fine if I don't use the router and connect directly.

*info:
linksys wrt54gl
Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/10/09) min

Answer (score 1):

[RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) uses tcp communication for session control between clients and server. So the server will have to listen for clients. The default port for RTSP is `554`, however [examples on VLCj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/Streaming) use port `5555` so be advised. This port has to be [forwarded](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Port_Forwarding#Port_Forwarding_using_the_Webinterface) by the router from the WAN address to the LAN address of the streaming server.

Please don't confuse with RTP which uses multicast instead and broadcast to the LAN broadcast address! Doing broadcast through a router is difficult as it will have to re-broadcast to WAN.

Comment: I know how to forward a port, but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why. My code is exactly like in the rtsp example, and I get this: [043e639c] main stream out: creating httpd [043e639c] main stream out error: socket bind error (No error) [043e639c] main stream out error: cannot create socket(s) for HTTP host [043e639c] stream_out_rtp stream out error: cannot export SDP as RTSP

Comment: @Rs7: What port are you using? In fact, can you post your code in question or on pastebin.com? Are you using 127.0.0.1 as IP address? It seems you're trying to open an address:port that is not available on that machine.

Comment: I'm using the WAN IP, ports from 13371-13400. pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Ggfa6jKp .    And I don't have any problems if I don't use the router and connect directly.

Comment: @Rs7: You should be using the localhost or LAN IP. The WAN IP is attached to the router, not to the computer where you run VLCj. That computer only knows about it's addresses.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It doesn't make sense using WAN IP but I tried using local/LAN IP the first time and still it didn't work. Now, on client I get this: [19c76a84] live555 demux error: no data received in 10s, aborting

Comment: @Rs7: I used your code for some testing. I'm not able to test it with a WRT54GL (maybe in 10-11 hours) but from my initial tests I found out that if I use the localhost IP for the server and then connect from the client to the LAN address it will not work. I need to be using the correct LAN address on the server as well. Can you test and see if using the LAN address fixes the problem. If not, let me know and I'll try to test it through my WRT54GL.